# FlushMode AUTO is not working with JPA and Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

We're currently migrating a legacy application written in `Spring/Hibernate` to `Spring Boot` (for having a less verbose config and other benefits). 
Because `Spring Boot` adheres to `JPA`, we have to 'migrate' our legacy code - written in `native Hibernate` (version 5) - to `JPA`. 
We're now facing an issue where Hibernate doesn't flush the session before firing a query, even when `FlushMode` is defined `AUTO`

Config looks as follows:

1) Main Spring Boot Config that is the entry of the application

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
@Slf4j(topic = "system")
public class MainApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MainApp.class, args);
    }
```

2) Persistence Config: 
- creates a `JPA Transaction Manager`;
- creates a `HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean` to prevent we don't have to adapt all places where a `SessionFactory` is used (and autowired) by `EntityManagerFactory` and to ensure `SessionFactory` and `EntityManagerFactory` both participate in same (JPA) `Transaction`.

```
@Configuration
public class PersistenceConfig {
  @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactoryBean.getObject());
        transactionManager.setDefaultTimeout(30);

        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean) {
        HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactoryBean.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactoryBean.getObject());

        return sessionFactoryBean;
    }
 }
```

The responsible code that generates the issue is as follows:

```
@Override
public void deletePossibleAnswerAndRemoveFromQuestion(Long definitionId, Long questionId, Long possibleAnswerId) {
    Definition definition = checkEntity(Definition.class, definitionId);
    Question question = checkEntity(Question.class, questionId);
    PossibleAnswer possibleAnswer = checkEntity(PossibleAnswer.class, possibleAnswerId);

    question.remove(possibleAnswer);

    if (definition.isHasRefinement()) {
         // this fires a 'select count(*) ...' query
        if (!possibleAnswerRepository.existsByType(definitionId, QuestionType.REFINE)) {
            definition.markNoRefinementsPresent();
        }
    }
}
```

A PossibleAnswer (child) entity is removed from a Question (parent) entity by performing a cascading delete as shown in the code below:

```
@Table(name = "questions")
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
public class Question extends AbstractEntity {

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "question", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private Set<PossibleAnswer> possibleAnswers = new HashSet<>();

public void remove(PossibleAnswer possibleAnswer) {
    getPossibleAnswers().remove(possibleAnswer);
    possibleAnswer.setQuestion(null);
}
```

The `remove` method is a convenience method that ensures both ends of bidirectional association are decoupled.

The big problem now is that `question.remove(possibleAnswer)` is propagated to database just before commit time. 
Put in other words: the cascading remove generates a delete query which is triggered **after** the 'count' query causing stale results as it depends on the PossibleAnswer being deleted.

Things we checked:
1) `FlushMode` of the `Session` and default `FlushMode` of `SessionFactory`/`EntityManagerFactory` -> both are set to `AUTO` 
2) Manually adding `session.flush()` before query is triggered -> this gives desired result where `question.remove(possibleAnswer)` is propagated to DB before firing query 
3) We don't face the issue in our unit-test when running `native Hibernate`

Does anyone have a clue why we encounter this strange behavior???

-- **UPDATE 1**-- 

Things I've checked: 
1) Default FlushMode 'AUTO' is correctly set on EntityManager;
2) 'count' query is executed BEFORE cascading remove.

-- **UPDATE 2**-- 

It seems when the 'count' query is executed, Hibernate first checks (code depicted below) if the Session must be flushed before really executing the query.

```
    protected boolean autoFlushIfRequired(Set querySpaces) throws HibernateException {
    errorIfClosed();
    if ( !isTransactionInProgress() ) {
        // do not auto-flush while outside a transaction
        return false;
    }
    AutoFlushEvent event = new AutoFlushEvent( querySpaces, this );
    listeners( EventType.AUTO_FLUSH );
    for ( AutoFlushEventListener listener : listeners( EventType.AUTO_FLUSH ) ) {
        listener.onAutoFlush( event );
    }
    return event.isFlushRequired();
}
```

The method `isTransactionInProgress`determines if a flush must be performed.
The implementation looks like follows:

```
@Override
public boolean isTransactionInProgress() {
    checkTransactionSynchStatus();
    return !isClosed() && transactionCoordinator.getTransactionDriverControl()
            .getStatus() == TransactionStatus.ACTIVE && transactionCoordinator.isJoined();
}
```

It seems that
 `transactionCoordinator.getTransactionDriverControl().getStatus()` returns `NOT_ACTIVE` and `transactionCoordinator.isJoined()` returns `false`.

This is causing the issue that cascaded delete is not executed before firing the query. 
I really don't have any idea why the underlying transaction is not is progress.

My setup is plain Spring Boot and Hibernate where I have a `Service` method annotated `@Transactional` so all underlying db-calls should be executed in one transaction.

Comment: have you tried setting the flush mode to auto on the query itself?

Comment: @Maciej It doesn't have any effect to set flushmode on query itself. On the other hand calling session.flush() does help. Weird thing is we shouldn't do this at all...

Comment: can you post the query exectuion itself?

Comment: @Maciej Please see my updated question

Answer (score 6):

There's a difference between the Hibernate legacy [`FlushMode`](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-does-jpa-and-hibernate-define-the-auto-flush-mode/) and JPA specification.

If you upgrade to Hibernate 5.2, it all depends on how you bootstrap Hibernate. If you bootstrap using the JPA way (e.g. `persistence.xml`), then the JPA behavior will be used. If you bootstrap through the `SessionFactoryBuilder`, the legacy behavior is considered.

I suspect that the `count` query is a native SQL query since entity queries should trigger a flush on both legacy and JPA modes.

So, you have multiple options:

1. You can bootstrap as JPA. This means you have to use the `LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean` instead of `LocalSessionFactoryBean`.
2. You can use [`FlushMode.ALWAYS`](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpahibernate-flush-strategies/). Make sure that every new `Session` is set with the `FlushMode.ALWAYS`: `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().setFlushMode(FlushMode.ALWAYS);`
3. You call a `session.flush()` manually prior to any native SQL query.

### Update

> It seems that
> transactionCoordinator.getTransactionDriverControl().getStatus()
> returns NOT_ACTIVE and transactionCoordinator.isJoined() returns
> false.

Most likely there is a problem with the Spring transaction management config. Make sure the Spring framework version is compatible with the Hibernate 5 you are using.

Also, check the debug stack trace if the `TransactionInterceptor` is there. If it's not, then you are not running within a transactional context.