# Spring-boot and Hibernate: How to flush data?

Tags: database, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have a problem with spring-boot + hibernate and my database.
When I save an entity with CrudRepository.save(...), sometimes my entity was only saved from JPA, but it's not in the database.

Thought that the flush mode was not set, i put the following config in the application.yaml but it didn't change anything. Maybe the mode was not set?

```
spring:
   liquibase:
      enabled: true
      change-log: classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml
   datasource:
      url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:26257/mydb?sslmode=disable
      username: myuser
   jpa:
      properties:
         hibernate:
            dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect
            flushMode: ALWAYS
         org:
            hibernate:
              flushMode: ALWAYS
      show-sql: true
      database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect
      hibernate:
         ddl-auto: create
logging:
   level:
      org.hibernate.SQL: DEBUG
      org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl: ERROR
      org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder: TRACE
server:
  port: 8081
```

```
@Repository
public interface PermissionRepository extends CrudRepository<Permission, Integer> {

}
```

Any idea? 
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I see in `application.yml` that you use liquibase that leds me to think you use it to manage your db. Soo, firstly you shouldn't set `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` to create, but `validate`, I think. :)

Then it would be great if you show us the entity/entities and the method where you use the crudrepository.

So, it's up to your entity i.e. is there any @OneToMany or @ManyToOne relation? 
Do you use transactionManager(s)?

Regarding `jpa hibernate flushMode settings`:
It all depends on how you bootstrap Hibernate. 
Entity queries should trigger a flush on both legacy and JPA modes with the default flushMode (AUTO).

[In addition, maybe you should read this ticket as well with the answer of Vlad Mihalcea.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42253404/flushmode-auto-is-not-working-with-jpa-and-hibernate)